# Почему запрос выдает отчет с перекрестными значениями как с cross join?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

нужно чтоб было 4 записи а выдает аж 16

```
SELECT 
       b.PAYMENT_ID,
       b.DESTINATION_ID,
       b.PAY_SUM,
       b.COMMISSION,
       b.PAY_DATE,
       s.EXTERNAL,
       s.ADR,
       s.FIO,
       s.PASSPORT,
       s.COUNTER1,
       s.COUNTER2,
       s.COUNTER3
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        PAYMENT_ID,
        DESTINATION_ID,
        PAY_SUM,
        COMMISSION,
        PAY_DATE,
        EXTERNAL,
        ADR,
        FIO,
        PASSPORT,
        COUNTER1,
        COUNTER2,
        COUNTER3
     FROM XMLTABLE('/XML/request/payments/payment/user_data'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<XML>
  <request type="PAYMENT">
    <pack>
      <pack_Id>7065528</pack_Id>
      <cash>2300.00</cash>
      <summ>2290.00</summ>
      <balance>10.00</balance>
    </pack>
    <payments>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12345</payment_id>
        <destination_Id>21523</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>118.12</pay_sum>
        <commission>30.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.290</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>30001625-093558</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, Лермонтова, 104, 005</adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1/>
          <counter2/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12346</payment_id>
        <destination_Id>9582</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>103.00</pay_sum>
        <commission>0.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.283</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>60306747</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, Лермонтова, 104, 5</adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1>0</counter1>
          <counter2/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12347</payment_id>
        <reverse_payment_id/>
        <org_id>131</org_id>
        <destination_Id>15781</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>558.88</pay_sum>
        <commission>0.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.280</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>170202147</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, Лермонтова, 104, 5</adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1/>
          <counter2/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12348</payment_id>
        <destination_Id>9582</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>1480.00</pay_sum>
        <commission>0.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.273</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>60005470</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, УЛ 25 ЛЕТ ОКТЯБРЯ, 20, </adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1>0</counter1>
          <counter2/>
          <counter3/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
    </payments>
  </request>
</XML>
')
                  COLUMNS
                      PAYMENT_ID     number PATH 'payment_id',
                      DESTINATION_ID number PATH 'destination_Id',
                      PAY_SUM        number PATH 'pay_sum',
                      COMMISSION     number PATH 'commission',
                      PAY_DATE       VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'pay_date',
                      EXTERNAL       VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'external',
                      ADR            VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'adr',
                      FIO            VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'fio',
                      PASSPORT       VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'pasp',
                      COUNTER1       NUMBER PATH 'counter1',
                      COUNTER2       NUMBER PATH 'counter2',
                      COUNTER3       NUMBER PATH 'counter3') a
     ) s,
    (SELECT 
        PAYMENT_ID,
        DESTINATION_ID,
        PAY_SUM,
        COMMISSION,
        PAY_DATE,
        EXTERNAL,
        ADR,
        FIO,
        PASSPORT,
        COUNTER1,
        COUNTER2,
        COUNTER3
     FROM XMLTABLE('/XML/request/payments/payment'
                  PASSING XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<XML>
  <request type="PAYMENT">
    <pack>
      <pack_Id>7065528</pack_Id>
      <cash>2300.00</cash>
      <summ>2290.00</summ>
      <balance>10.00</balance>
    </pack>
    <payments>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12345</payment_id>
        <destination_Id>21523</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>118.12</pay_sum>
        <commission>30.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.290</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>30001625-093558</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, Лермонтова, 104, 005</adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1/>
          <counter2/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12346</payment_id>
        <destination_Id>9582</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>103.00</pay_sum>
        <commission>0.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.283</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>60306747</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, Лермонтова, 104, 5</adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1>0</counter1>
          <counter2/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12347</payment_id>
        <reverse_payment_id/>
        <org_id>131</org_id>
        <destination_Id>15781</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>558.88</pay_sum>
        <commission>0.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.280</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>170202147</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, Лермонтова, 104, 5</adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1/>
          <counter2/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
      <payment>
        <payment_id>12348</payment_id>
        <destination_Id>9582</destination_Id>
        <pay_sum>1480.00</pay_sum>
        <commission>0.00</commission>
        <pay_date>2023-01-16 10:21:06.273</pay_date>
        <user_data>
          <external>60005470</external>
          <adr>МАГНИТОГОРСК, УЛ 25 ЛЕТ ОКТЯБРЯ, 20, </adr>
          <fio>ДОБРОЛЮБОВА ТАМАРА АЛЕКСАНДРОВНА</fio>
          <pasp/>
          <counter1>0</counter1>
          <counter2/>
          <counter3/>
        </user_data>
      </payment>
    </payments>
  </request>
</XML>
')
                  COLUMNS
                      PAYMENT_ID     number PATH 'payment_id',
                      DESTINATION_ID number PATH 'destination_Id',
                      PAY_SUM        number PATH 'pay_sum',
                      COMMISSION     number PATH 'commission',
                      PAY_DATE       VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'pay_date',
                      EXTERNAL       VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'external',
                      ADR            VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'adr',
                      FIO            VARCHAR2(100) PATH 'fio',
                      PASSPORT       VARCHAR2(20) PATH 'pasp',
                      COUNTER1       NUMBER PATH 'counter1',
                      COUNTER2       NUMBER PATH 'counter2',
                      COUNTER3       NUMBER PATH 'counter3') );
```

b[image: вот что он выдает]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: Так у Вас там запятая - это собственно и есть CROSS JOIN... тем более что нет и никакого WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить секцию WHERE по аналогии с простым примером:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот результат после добавления такой секции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также таблицы можно соединить с помощью JOIN